# Background color of the code of the same { } section? [ECLPISE]

Tags: eclipse, appearance, text-coloring

**Hello!**

I was wondering if there is an option to color the background of the same code section between { }?
For example this is what it looks like in BlueJ:
[BlueJ example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaCaN.png)

If coloring isn't an option is there any other way to see what { is connected to the other }? Maybe lines or something...

Anyways, thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not built into Eclipse, but the [**EditBox** plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/editbox#group-screenshots) you might install does this. The [**Indent Guide** plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/indent-guide#group-screenshots) shows lines. You might find more such plugins on the [Eclipse Marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org).

Comment: Unfortunately the devs still haven't updated the plugin as most of the comments say it doesn't work with the latest eclipse. I'll try it anyways,Thank you!!

Comment: @Shulmanovsky EditBox was updated on January 21, 2021 and newer comments say it works in Eclipse 2020-12, unlike older comments. If something does not work, report it to the provider of the plugin and since it's open source, if you as Java developer can fix it, preferably with a patch.